# How to get a freshly Inserted Id with reactjs (Axios)?

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to retrieve the Id value of a freshly Inserted row in Mysql with react Axios.

*Here Is my code In node.js*

```js
app.post('/createProject', (req,res) => {
  const projectName = req.body.projectName;
  const tjm = req.body.tjm;
  const status = req.body.status;
  db.query("INSERT INTO projects (projectName, tjm, status) VALUES (?,?,?)",
  [projectName, tjm, status],
  (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      res.send("Values Inserted");
      res.send(result.insertId);
      console.log(result.insertId);
    }
  }
);
});
```

I try to get the `insertId` with a `UseState` hook;to use It in another Post request and store It in another table.

*The post request In react:*

```js
const [id, setId] = useState();
  const addProject = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/createProject", {
      projectName: projectName,
      tjm: tjm,
      status: "Inachevé"//Uncomplete,
    }).then((res) => {
      console.log("success");
      setId(res.data);
    });
  };
```

I try `console.log(id)` but I get undefined in the console.

*The post request to get the Inserted Id of the project:*

```js
const addWork = () => {
    Axios.post("http://localhost:3001/createWork", {
        EmpID: id_e,//I get that Id from a drop-down list 
        PrID: id_p,// the Id of the Inserted project who I can't get
    }).then(() => {
      console.log("success");
    });
  };
```

When I fill my Inputs In the frontend and send the the data (prjectName,tjm & status),the data is stored normally and the **insertId** consoled In the backend but I can't get it in my client side.

How I can access to **insertId** in the frontend and store It In another table at the same time when creating a new Project?

**note:** I think that I should use `async/await` to make `addWork` function wait until `addProject` execute but the probleme Is how to get the **insertId** In the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `res.send()` twice. You would probably want to send json, which works like the following: `res.status(200).json({message: "Message",data: lastInsertedID})`.
You would then need to make sure to correctly access the id in the frontend. Therefore you can print the whole json response object from on the console and  make your way through the json object until you reach the id.

Comment: I try something like that `res.status(200).json({message: "Message",data: lastInsertedID})`, and use just one `res.send`, and like that In frontend `setId(JSON.parse(res.data))`,but still get `undefined`

Comment: Do only use the `res.status(200).json({message: "Message",data: lastInsertedID})` and not the `res.send`.  Then, log the response output in frontend to console. Inside the response object there will be the json u sent from backend. If you're still having trouble please send the console output.

Comment: I use only `res.status(200).json({message: "Message",data: lastInsertedID})`,the console output In my frontend Is `undefined`

Comment: do a `console.log(res)` and take a closer look on the response object.